# Webapplication authentication with refresh token is redirecting back to google login page

Tags: python, authentication, web-applications, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

We have our jenkins authentication setup using google oauth using OpenId Connect in Apache (Reference: https://cloudavail.com/2014/06/07/apache-auth-oidc-google-apps-2/).

In order to automate some of the jenkins jobs, we have to authenticate first.

I got the access token and refresh token using client-secrets.json in a python script during which authentication to google mail is already done.

I am using the following script to auto refresh the token using the refresh token and then use the new token to list all of the jobs or projects in Jenkins.

Why is it redirecting me to google login when I have already authorized with gmail during the authorize step while fetching the access token. It will be a great help, if anyone can help me resolve this.

Following is the script (token.json and extra.json contains token and client details)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import requests_oauthlib, json
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session, TokenUpdated

protected_url='<jenkins_url>/api/json?pretty=true'
refresh_url='https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token'

#Start here
TOKEN_FILE='token.json'
EXTRA_FILE='extra.json'

with open(TOKEN_FILE, 'r') as f:
   token = json.load(f)

with open(EXTRA_FILE, 'r') as f:
   extra = json.load(f)


client_id=extra['client_id']


def token_saver(token_temp):
   token = token_temp


from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
client = OAuth2Session(client_id, token=token, auto_refresh_url=refresh_url,auto_refresh_kwargs=extra, token_updater=token_saver)
token=client.refresh_token(refresh_url, **extra)
token_saver(token)
client = OAuth2Session(client_id, token=token)
r = client.get(protected_url)
print r.content
```

> token.json contents

```
   {
     "access_token": "{access_token}",
     "refresh_token": "{Refresh_token}",
     "id_token": "{id_token}",
     "token_type": "Bearer",
     "expires_in": "5"
    }
```

> extra.json contents

```
 {
 "client_id":"{client_id}",
  "client_secret":"{client_secret}"
}
```

Comment: Please can you edit your question and add more info about what you mean by _"I am trying to get the list of projects in Jenkins using the refresh token and client id and secret"_ ? Because you should not send the refresh token anywhere but the `/token` endpoint.

Comment: Ján Halaša - I elaborated the issue. Please let me know where I am going wrong in my approach.